# Bootstrap dropdown automatically capitilising menu options

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Anyone know why the the menu items are all capitilised while the markup is lower-case?  What can i do to stop this behaviour?

[image: pic]

Comment: Pick the selector by inspecting it and override it with `text-transform: none` in your custom styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom class in your css and add it to your ul tag class

```
.textdeco
{
text-transform:none;
}

<ul class="dropdown-menu textdeco"...>
```

or directly inline

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="text-transform:none"...>
```

W3Schools explains it nicely

[Text-Transform](http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_text_text-transform.asp)